# Boot to ubuntu from windows

Tags: boot, 16.04, windows-10, reboot

I hope you can help me, I was wondering if it's possible to boot Ubuntu directly from windows 10 and how (I mean that I don't want to wait to select entry in grub, boot directly to ubuntu) ? I found a software named ireboot but it only displays reboot to windows 10.

Comment: No, you can't boot into one OS from another. You can install one insede the other using e.g. Virtualbox.

Comment: If new UEFI system, you can use the UEFI one time boot key, often f10 or f12, check your manual and directly choose which system to boot.

Comment: Pilot6, it's possible, the answer is below, thanks oldfred for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer of how to achieve that.

1. First it's necessary install EasyBCD 2.3 on windows 10.
2. Open EasyBCD and add linux entry to booloader and save.
3. Search for an option named BCD deploymeny and write windows vista+ mbr
4. Install software iReboot, you can get it inside EasyBCD application.
5. Reboot your pc, yoo will see the two entries on bootloader, select windows 10
6. Once windows loads, iReboot starts automatically, if you right click on the icon it will show some options, first enable reboot on selection and then if you click on the new entry (linux or whatever you named) the pc will restart and boot to linux.

An thats all.